# Warn if extraction via $ for data.frame returns NULL

Tags: r

Recently I became aware of `options("warnPartialMatchDollar")` which defaults to `FALSE`. As I use the `$` operator quite frequently to extract columns from `data.frame`s in scripts I changed the option to `TRUE` to get informed whenever I made a typo which would lead to unintended behaviour.

However, I wonder if there is something similar if extraction by `$` fails due to non-existend columns? Typo pitfall is here again as one gets no warning in scripts. The extraction just returns `NULL` (if there is no match). How do people handle this situation?

Sure, I am aware of `df[ , c("non_existant_var")]` which throws an error for non existing columns. Extraction by `$` is just too convenient...

Comment: Personally I tend to avoid `$` in non-interactive use.

Comment: I am also using the `$` only in non-interactive mode or (not very consistent) if I created a column on my own. The best thing with `$` is the autocompletion that why it is convenient in a way. But when I am developing script, a lot of the column names need to be variable and therefor I can not use the $ anymore.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an option in R.

Comment: Would doin something like `if(is.null(df$column)) warning("your custom warning")` help?

Comment: @RichardScriven That would be a solution for a one time application but unfortunately not for all occasions of `$`. I was really looking for an option to turn on/off to make the usage of `$` in scripts more robust.